# How do I solve the following PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How do I solve the following PDE for $y(x,t)$ and the given auxiliary
conditions for $0≤x≤1$ and $t≥0$?

$$y_{tt}=4y_{xx}$$

$$y(0,t)=y(1,t)=0$$

$$y(x,0)=0$$

$$y_t(x,0)=\sin(\pi x)-\sin(3\pi x)$$

I know I'm somehow supposed to use separation of variables to reach the answer:

$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(2\pi t)\sin(\pi x)-\frac{1}{6\pi}\sin(6\pi t)\sin(3\pi x)$$

However, I don't know how to get to this point. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write Y(x,t) = X(x)T(t) then substitute into the PDE to get

$T''(t)X(x) = 4X''(x)T(t)$

Divide both sides by $X(x)T(t)$ to get

$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)} = 4\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$.

Both sides are functions of independent variables, so it must be a constant, call it $-\lambda^2$ (the negative and square are solely for convenience). Then you have to solve

$\frac{T''(t)}{T(t)} = -\lambda^2 = 4\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$.

The obvious solutions are sines and cosines (or complex exponentials if you prefer). To determine the amplitudes of the sines and cosines, use the initial conditions. I'll sketch part of the solution.

Solving the PDE we have $X''(x) + 4\lambda^2 X(x) = 0$. The solutions to this are given by $X(x) = A\cos(2\lambda x) + B\sin(2\lambda x)$. To determine the values of A and $\lambda$, we turn to the boundary conditions. The boundary conditions tell us that $X(0) = 0 = A$ and $X(1) = 0 = B\sin(2\lambda)$.

The right boundary condition gives that $\lambda = \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$. Therefore the overall expression for $X$ will be given as a sum of sines (with the values of $k$ to be determined). So we have

$X(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_n\sin((2k+1)\pi x)$.

Continue this procedure for T and then combine the results to get the overall solution.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  The problem makes much more sense now!

Comment: You're very welcome!